# Computer names that are used by Dropbox and Office 365

Tags: windows-10, office365, dropbox, computer-name

When I perform an install from Office 365 on one of my computers, it uses a computer name that is not the one that can be seen under settings. This had caused me some trouble identifying active software installations from the administrator app of Office 365.

Now I have a problem of a conflicted copy in Dropbox and the file it has created also refers to a name no longer in my computers, it is like "DESKTOP -XXXXX".

I already searched the registry for:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SchedulingAgent\OldName
```

This brought a "DESKTOP - XXXXX" value for one of my computer but not on others.

If it is possible to recuperate this old name it would be of help.

Comment: Where exactly did you change the name of the computer?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember your original computer name? If you remember the original name, you can change it manually.

Right-click the computer -- properties -- advanced system settings -- computer name -- change, change the name you want to restore.

If you forget the original name, please check if you have regular system backups and restore it to the date before you changed the computer name